# Why isn't the CSS relative positioning working correctly in this example?

Tags: css, css-position

I was doing some tests with CSS positioning and I noticed an odd behavior.

Let's say I have an absolutely positioned container div (red). Inside this div I want to place two blocks (green and blue), with a relative position to the container. These blocks should stick to the top and have a 50 pixels distance between them, like below

[image]

So I'm thinking I should use `top:0px; left:0px;` for the first one, to place him near the top left corner. I add 50 to its width for the spacing and I get `top:0px; left: 100px;` for the second block. (jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BBog/Wfqvc/)).

Instead of seeing the expected behavior, I get this positioning

[image]

It seems that the second block has its `top`relative to the first block, and not to the parent container. So the correct CSS code for the second block should be `top: -50px; left: 100px;`, like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BBog/Wfqvc/1/) fiddle.

This isn't the first time I noticed this. In some cases, the `left` property it's the one at fault, in this case it was `top`.

Anyway, I know **how** to fix these problems and get the correct display, but I don't understand **why** isn't it working like I think it should.

It's very likely that I misunderstood something about this whole absolute/relative positioning, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second block has its `top` and `left` relative to *itself*, not the first block or the parent container.

When you position something relatively, its offset values shift it in those directions away from what its original position would have been before you applied relative positioning. The offsets are never based on the positions of its siblings, ancestors or descendants (unless they are `auto`, which is their initial value).

Comment: It should also be noted that changing `relative` to `absolute` would solve the problem in this case, since the parent already has positioning ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wfqvc/2/)).

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thank you for the answer, I will accept in 7 minutes